# ECG of heart transplant patients

Tags: cardiology

I am studying ECGs of heart transplant patients. 
The difficult thing is that there is so little available data publicly. 
I must apply for data in my universities. 
It would be also great if something is public.

I have searched several databases and contacted some authors directly. 
Some findings

- No heart transplant data in Physionet, online search tool [here](http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM).
- No heart transplant data of ECGI with Dr Rudy (personal email)

I am waiting answers or working with application for

- Dr Rudy's [company](http://www.cardioinsight.com)
- University of Helsinki's database (under process for application)
- Some technical universities in Finland (these have connections where are good data but they do not hold data themselves)

**Is there any ECG data about heart transplant patients?**

Comment: [This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2306833) might get you started on how to look for such (it's also interesting). I don't know if the National Center for Biotechnology Information might be a resource.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Interesting. Citing articles are also good resources: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&sciodt=0,5&cites=http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/81/3/821.abstract&scipsc= Let's see if any data is public.

Comment: are you looking for images or anything in particular coz I found a bunch after a google search. Most of them are heterotrophic heart transplants though

Comment: @TheLastWord I am looking for data (raw numerical data). Not pictures. Feel free to propose any data which you found so I can take a look at them if they are appropriate.